# Chunk data transfer datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, datatables

I'm trying to transfer data in multiple chunks after a while in a single request from the express.js server to the js client. But it doesn't work, the connection closes after I send the first chunk of res.json(data) data;   The task is to output data in table as it arrives

```
export async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  try {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const data = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    ];
    res.json(data); // At this point, the connection is closed
    await sleep(60000); // Simulation of operation
    const nextData = [
      { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Item 4' },
    ];
    res.json(nextData);
    res.end();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
  }
}
```

and my client's code:

```
const dataTable = $('#my-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'name' },
        ],
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'get_data',
            type: 'POST',
            dataSrc: '',
        },
        processing: true,
    });
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].